# Common Sconstruct file like Makefile.common

Tags: scons

Is there a way to have a Sconstruct.common at the top level directory that has all the compiler/linker options that are common to individual subdirectories and have separate Sconstruct files within each individual subdirectory with custom options that specify additional arguments to the compiler/linker options ?

(Similiar to having Makefile.common in the top-level dir and individual Makefile in subdirs including Makefile.common and adding extra args using variables)

thanks,
Prakash

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Scons is usually organized with a top-level SConstruct file that sets up common build commands (in an Environment) and SConscript files in sub-directories of the project that build local artifacts (objects, libraries, executables, etc). In the top-level SConstruct, you list the SConscript files that you want to include using the [SConscript command](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SConscript%28%29). In your SConscript files you can either override certain environment variables as needed in a particular build command, or you can Clone your common build environment and override variables that way.

I highly recommend reading through the [Scons User's Guide](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html).

Also, Scons is python, so you can also `import` python code for build or deploy actions that might be common across projects.

Comment: thanks, Dave. Got it to work with Export(), Import() and Return() methods